# sql injection operator explanation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning about SQL injection, and I learned that one type of blind sql injection is to find the number of columns in a table like this for example:

> category.php?id=10' order by 5--

But then I saw something like the following:

> > category.php?id=10' order by 5--+

Can anyone explain the purpose of the plus sign? I'm not sure how MySQL handles that operator in this context. Can anyone think of an example of how this applies if the query is being executed through PHP.

Comment: Why don't you run it and see what happens?

Comment: See [How does the SQL injection from the “Bobby Tables” XKCD comic work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/332367)

Comment: @Jocelyn: Whilst that question may help answer this one, they are not duplicates.